What equation models the shear rate as a function of the cross-sectional height of a square channel in lamina flow?
I am trying to model how shear rate changes across the cross section of a square channel (in a microfluidic device), depending on the height+width, fluid viscosity (assuming water) given it is fully developed lamina flow. The equations I have found are only valid for either aspect ratios <0.5, or for average shear rates (which is not helpful given that I want to find the maximum shear rate in the channel).
Ultimately from the equation I will then plot a graph of the shear rate across the cross-section, in MATLAB.

There is a solution in the literature for the velocity variation for laminar flow in a rectangular channel.  In the case of a square cross section, the maximum shear rate is at the center of each wall.
